# "Windows Live" folder in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, shell, windows-8.1

I created a custom shell command for command prompt. In Windows 7, I stored it in  *C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live*. I was able to run this command from **cmd**.

I tried to register this command in Windows 8.1 (64-bit) but I don't have the folder  *Windows Live* in *Microsoft Shared*.

How can I register this custom command in Windows 8.1?

[Here is the GitHub Link.](https://github.com/detroitstudio/fuck)

Comment: Install the command into a different location and register that as the location in question? You happened to choose a folder that got added to the user's `%PATH%` in the old environment. You can add that path to the user's `%PATH%`, which will then allow your app to run in that case.

Comment: Yes, I just found it. But how I can add this path ?

Comment: 20 seconds of google would find you videos or websites that will tell you how to do that.

Comment: Yes, thank you i found it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found soloution. Thanks @Petesh

1. Create folder *C:\CustomCommands*
2. Open **Computer** and **right-click** on any white space, then select **properties** from the context menu.
3. When the **System section of Control Panel** opens, click on the **Advanced system settings** hyperlink in the left hand pane.
4. Then you will need to click on the **Environment Variables** button.
5. In order to add an entry to your path, you need to precede the folder name with a semi-colon. For example, if i want to add the CustomCommands folder which is on the root of your C drive to my path i would the following to the end of the Variable value field:

   ;C:\CustomCommands
6. Copy **.bat** file to this directory
7. Restart